# Set Attribute with ESQL in XMLNSC for XML Array

Tags: sql, xml, messagebroker

I am succeeding in adding a `name="xxxxxx"` attribute to an XML element when there is one, but not for an array of repeated elements.

For instance, I can create a `<Broker name="xxxxxx"`> element with the following line:

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.SystemDetails.BrokerDetails.Broker.(XMLNSC.Attribute)name = 
FIELDVALUE(InputRoot.XMLNSC.broker.(XMLNSC.Attribute)name);
```

And can create an array of XML Elements with the following line:

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.SystemDetails.BrokerDetails.Servers.Server[] = 
    SELECT ITEM FIELDVALUE(A.(XMLNSC.Attribute)name)
    FROM InputRoot.XMLNSC.broker.executionGroups.executionGroup[] AS A;
```

Which gives:

```
<SystemDetails>
     <BrokerDetails>
           <Broker name="xxxxxx" />
           <Servers>
                <Server>xxx1</Server>
                <Server>xxx2</Server>
                <Server>xxx3</Server>
                <Server>xxx4</Server>
           </Servers>
     </BrokerDetails>
</SystemDetails>
```

But cannot combine the two methods to create what I want which is the following:

```
<SystemDetails>
     <BrokerDetails>
           <Broker name="xxxxxx" />
           <Servers>
                <Server name="xxx1" />
                <Server name="xxx2" />
                <Server name="xxx3" />
                <Server name="xxx4" />
           </Servers>
     </BrokerDetails>
</SystemDetails>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think, you can only do this by iterating over the executionGroup elements (in a FOR loop for example) and creating the corresponding Server elements by a SET manually. You don't really have any way to change the output format of a select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't produce your output in one select statement but with two it's possible.

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.SystemDetails.BrokerDetails.Broker.(XMLNSC.Attribute)name = 
    SELECT ITEM R.(XMLNSC.Attribute)name FROM InputRoot.XMLNSC.broker AS R;  

SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.SystemDetails.BrokerDetails.Servers.Server[] =  
    SELECT FIELDVALUE(A.(XMLNSC.Attribute)name) AS (XMLNSC.Attribute)name FROM   
       InputRoot.XMLNSC.broker.executionGroups.executionGroup[] AS A;
```

Which gives the following result.

```
<SystemDetails>
    <BrokerDetails>
        <Broker name="DEV.ADAP2B"/>
        <Servers>
           <Server name="JumpStart"/>
           <Server name="SMUDGER"/>
        </Servers>
    </BrokerDetails>
</SystemDetails>
```

I'm not sure you could do it in one select statement as you're mixing scalar value for Broker element with List for Servers.